# how to display image plus text in List view using cursor adapter from SQLite? with search view using name

Tags: sqlite, listview, android-sqlite, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

i am getting this error can any one post the solution to me

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         android.database.StaleDataException: Attempting to access a closed CursorWindow.Most probable cause: cursor is deactivated prior to calling this method.
    ImageCursorAdapter.java

```
private Cursor c;
private Context context;
byte[] image;

public ImageCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.c = c;
    this.context = context;
}

public View getView(int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = inView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_view__patients, null);
    }
    this.c.moveToPosition(pos);

 String firstName = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
   String lastName = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("Name"));
// String titleStr = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("title"));
    image = this.c.getBlob(this.c.getColumnIndex("Image"));


ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.all_img);
if (image != null) {
    // If there is no image in the database "NA" is stored instead of a blob
    // test if there more than 3 chars "NA" + a terminating char if more than
    // there is an image otherwise load the default
    if (image.length > 0) {
        iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length));
    } else {
        iv.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    }
}
TextView fname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.db_id);
fname.setText(firstName);

TextView lname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name_id);
lname.setText(lastName);

// this.c.close();
//  this.c.moveToNext();
return (v);


}
```

}

this is my main activity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    open();
    db.getReadableDatabase();
 db.getWritableDatabase();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV);

    int layoutstyle = R.layout.activity_view__patients;
    xml_id = new int[]{
            R.id.db_id,
            R.id.name_id,
            R.id.all_img
    };
    column = new String[]{
            "patients._id",
            "patients.Name",
            "patients.Image"

    };
    row = db.fetchAllData();
    adapter = new ImageCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), layoutstyle, row, column, xml_id);
    // adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, layoutstyle, row, column, xml_id);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //onClick function
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterview, View view, int position, long id) {
            Cursor row = (Cursor) adapterview.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String Id = row.getString(row.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            String name = row.getString(row.getColumnIndex("Name"));

            //go to detailsContact page
            Intent todetais = new Intent(ViewPatients2.this, TabViewActivity.class);
            todetais.putExtra("ListViewClickedItemValue", Id);
            // todetais.putExtra("NAME", name);
            // todetais.putExtra("NUMBER", number);
            //  todetais.putExtra("EMAIL", email);
            // todetais.putExtra("ADDRESS", address);
            startActivity(todetais);
        }
    });

    //dispay data by filter
   et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit4);

    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                                  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                  }

                                  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                                  }

                                  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                                      adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());


                                  }
                              });
    adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            return db.fetchdatabyfilter(constraint.toString(), "patients.Name");
        }
    });


enter code here

}

private void open() {
    sqLiteDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase(DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    row.close();
    db.close();
}
```

}

this is my DatabaseHelper.java

```
public Cursor fetchdatabyfilter(String inputText,String Name) throws SQLException {
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDb=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor row = null;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM "+Patient_Table;
        if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
            row = sqlDb.rawQuery(query, null);
        }else {
            query = "SELECT * FROM "+Patient_Table+" WHERE "+Name+" like '%"+inputText+"%'";
            row = sqlDb.rawQuery(query, null);
        }
       if (row != null) {
            row.moveToFirst();

        }

        return row;
    }
```

Comment: You are very likely closing the cursor before calling the method. If this isn't simply a matter of removing the `your_cursor.close()`. The edit your question to include the code that invokes the adapter and perhaps the code that creates and returns the Cursor.

Comment: sorry i didn't get you will you tell where is the actual problem

Comment: I am getting image with text from Sqlite in list view but whenever enter name for search in the edit text box getting error like cursor is deactivated prior to calling this method.

Comment: Are you using and Intent/ startactivity to call theMainActivity in the TabViewActivity to return? Or are you using finish() ?.  Additionally in fetchdatabyfilter the `if (row != null) {  row.moveToFirst(); } should be removed a) Cursor will never be null b) there should be no need to move the cursor (this may affect the use of it in the adapter but shouldn't)`

Comment: yes even i removed what you told,but getting same error in my ImageCursorAdapter class where getting values from database getString column index

Comment: just forget about tabviewactivity problem is in MainActivity while searching name from edit text box

Comment: Add the full stack-trace to the question.

Comment: once check my ImageCursorAdapter class  error showing in getView method at  String firstName = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("_id"));